# Using ReplayKit with MacCatalyst

Tags: replaykit, mac-catalyst

I have an app for iOS that also runs on macOS via MacCatalyst.  I have just started using ReplayKit to add screen recording to the app.  It is working well under iOS, but when used on Mac I get the following error when calling startRecording()

RPDaemonProxy: startRecordingWithHandler: proxy error: 4099

Any idea how to fix this?